# Is it the right way using `[weak self]` in swift closure?

Tags: swift, closures, weak

I always using `[weak self]` in swift closure to prevent reference cycle.
Here is the code below, is it the correct way?

```
someTask(completion: {[weak self] (result) in
        if self == nil {  
            return
        }

        //is it safe when reach here? 

        self!.xxx = yyy
        self!.doLongTermWork()
        self!.finish()  //will crash when self is nil?
    })
```

Weak self does not keep a strong hold on the instance. So when `self.doLongTermWork()`, will `self` be set to `nil` again somewhere else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your pattern has race condition. If `self` was deallocated at the exact same time as your completion handler closure was executing, it could crash. As a general rule, avoid using the `!` forced unwrapping operator if you can.

1. I’d lean towards the `guard` “early exit” pattern (reducing nested braces, making code easier to read). The standard Swift 4.2 solution is:

   ```
   someTask { [weak self] result in
       guard let self = self else { return }

       self.xxx = yyy
       self.doLongTermWork()
       self.finish()
   }
   ```
2. Before Swift 4.2, which implemented [SE-0079](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0079-upgrade-self-from-weak-to-strong.md), we would have to do something like:

   ```
   someTask { [weak self] result in
       guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

       strongSelf.xxx = yyy
       strongSelf.doLongTermWork()
       strongSelf.finish()
   }
   ```

   You can see why we prefer the Swift 4.2 improvement, as this `strongSelf` syntax is inelegant.
3. The other obvious alternative is just:

   ```
   someTask { [weak self] result in
       self?.xxx = yyy
       self?.doLongTermWork()
       self?.finish()
   }
   ```

   Sometimes you need the “weak self - strong self dance” (the first two alternatives), but it would not appear to be the case here. This is likely sufficient.

There are other scenarios/edge cases that one might contemplate, but these are the basic approaches.

Comment: Can now do `guard let self else { return }`.

Answer (score 7):

You said:

```
someTask(completion: {[weak self] (result) in
    if self == nil {  
        return
    }
    //is it safe when reach here? 
    self!.xxx = yyy
})
```

No! You have not retained `self`, so in theory it might become `nil` at any time during the execution of the closure. It probably won't, but "probably" is not good enough. And exclamation marks are always an invitation to crash.

Do the weak-strong dance, and do it correctly:

```
someTask(completion: {[weak self] (result) in
    if let self = self {  // or let `self` before Swift 4
        // here, self is safe, because you made the reference strong again
        self.xxx = yyy
    }
})
```

Comment: Why not simply Optional Chaining?

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this from Swift 4.2

```
someTask(completion: {[weak self] (result) in
    guard let self = self { return }

    //it safe when reach here always

    self.xxx = yyy
    self.doLongTermWork()
    self.finish()
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have another confusion. When I want to weak many objects at a time, ex: `{[weak self], [weak obj1], [weak obj2].. in ...}`.    Is it thread safe to prevent the race condition.

Comment: @JamesZhang - The syntax would be `someTask { [weak self, weak obj1, weak obj2] in ... }`. And yes, you can do that, but in practice it’s extremely rare that you’d need to do that. You’d have to give us a practical example of when you intended to do this. But these `weak` capture references are for avoiding strong reference cycles and race conditions: It is, by no means, any guarantee of thread-safety. That’s a different and much broader topic.